# Ошибка при подключении webenginewidgets: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets

Tags: c++, qt

Я использую бесплатную версию qt 6.5.0 В менеджере пакетов Когда подключаю в pro файле `QT       += core gui sql webenginewidgets` пишет такую ошибку webenginewidgets: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets В менеджере пакетов этот пакет установлен. Также прочитал менеджере в установке доп. библиотек, что большинство доп. библиотек доступны для комерческой версии или LGPLv3. Хорошо что мне теперь делать качать и переводить проект на 5 версию или можно указать как то что это будет LGPLv3 ? Мне нужен этот модуль.

Comment: LGPLv3 не причём, это просто на вашей ответственности

Comment: а у вас компилятор то какой? не mingw случайно?

Comment: да mingw у меня

Comment: так там же (в установщике) в описании модуля написано, что для windows только msvc 2019, ну я думаю, что и 2022 будет работать