# Как поставить компилятор MVSC для работы с QWebEngineView?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно поставить компилятор MVSC потому что он работает с QWebEngineView Но если я ставлю такой компилятор в проекте получаю вот то что на картинке и кучу ошибок:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstddef:12:
> error: C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: stddef.h: No such
> file or directory,
>
> D:\qt\prj\untitled2\main.cpp:2: error: In included file: 'math.h' file
> not found
>
> D:\qt\prj\untitled2\main.cpp:11: error: Cannot initialize object
> parameter of type 'QWidget' with an expression of type 'MainWindow'

Как это все исправить я уже совсем запутался? Возможно надо до устанавливать какие то компоненты к Visual Studio Но почему qt вообще берет именно их компиляторы? Он же устанавливает кучу всего в том числе и эти компиляторы, дебагеры. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка выглядит так, будто другой компилятор (GCC?) пытается использовать хедеры от MSVC. *"MVSC потому что он работает с QWebEngineView"* Вот отсюда можно поподробнее?

Comment: Ну если вкратце я пытался подключить в pro файл QT += core gui  webenginewidgets у меня вылазила ошибка webenginewidgets: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets Мне написали что это из-за компилятора MinGw я начал пробовать переключать на MVSC но он не переключался. А потом в новом проекте вот это.

Comment: *"Мне написали что это из-за компилятора MinGw"* Кто и где написал?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1514971/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-webenginewidgets-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webengi

Comment: сделайте нормальный msvc kit, соберите им что-нибудь из example для теста, потом удалите у себя файл *.pro.user (выйдя из qtcreator), откройте свой проект, укажите msvc kit

Answer (score 1):

Открыл установщик Visual Studio и доустанавливал к ней возможность писать классические приложения на C++, также компиляторы MSVC там выделил (выделил все). После этого все заработало.